# What is making my Figma file so large when I create a PDF?

Tags: figma

I'm trying to understand why I'm getting 5.4MB PDF files when I use the TinyImageCompressor to create a PDF of the Figma file I've created.

The file has a frame that is 900 px wide and 7,200 pixels high. Inside that frame are ~30 text fields totaling 1,800 words.

Also inside that frame are about 5 optimized images that average 350 px wide by 300 px high.

Is there anything I could do when creating these files in Figma to get the PDF size down to something more like 1.5MB?

Thank you in advance!